# Override templates in profiles templates

Tags: 8

in drupal 8 I'd like to be able to override a template found at the root of Drupal in profiles/name/modules/menu/template/menu.html.
I tried to put it in the child theme in templates/ but both templates are taken into account, so my menu appears twice.
How can I fix this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand the question, so it shouldn't happen. BTW, try to enable twig debug to see the correct template file name to use  https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

Comment: Thank you for the answer
I've activated the twig debug but unfortunately the override is not working properly.